# How to find pixel points of particular portion of an image

Tags: android, image-processing, imageview

Part of my android app, I want to highlight a particular portion of an image.My task is that, when a user click/touch on that area it should be highlighted. So I need to find the pixel points of that region's boundary, which is to be highlighted. I don't have any idea about the image processing techniques. So please suggest suitable software that help me to find a solution.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "a particular portion" of your image - by position, by colour, by recognition of a particular kind of object? If you need the latter (more complex) you should edit your question to be more clear about this.

Comment: @svk, Sorry, I mean 'by position'. My task is that, when a user click/touch on that area it should be highlighted. So I need pixel values of that region's boundary which is to be highlighted

Answer (score 0):

Set OnTouchListener for the ImageView and in setOnTouchListener() {} consider **MotionEvent event** *event.getX()* and *event.getY()* which will give you cordinate values.

For pixel :
1. get bitmap
2. int pixel = bitmap.getPixel((int)event.getX(),(int)event.getY());

So in this way you will get pixel through you can animate that portion.

Comment: ,I just want to ask you whether the pixel for the image remains the same for different screen resolution ?

Comment: I have try that @ Bhavana Vadodariya, its showing me different pixel values for different screen resolutions.

Comment: @SalmanKhan u r asking the clicking point value(the x,y coordinate values) ? or total number of pixel value(dimensions) ?